# Rebase a feature branch onto a specific commit of another branch

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am trying to rebase a feature branch (branched off of master) onto a specific commit of another branch.
My initial status was the following

```
       C -- D            branch1
      /     
A -- B -- E -- F         master
                \
                         branch2 (zero commits after creating the branch)
```

I first rebased branch2 onto A in master which worked fine. My current status should (according to my understanding) be the following

```
       C -- D             branch1
      /
A -- B -- E -- F          master
 \
  B -- E -- F             branch2
```

I verified that branch2 branches off of master at commit A and is even with the master branch. What I now want to get is this

```
A -- B -- E -- F          master
 \
  B -- E -- F             branch2
   \
    C -- D                branch1
```

I tried

```
git checkout branch1
git rebase --onto B branch2
```

But this resulted in a whole bunch of conflicts and I don't understand at all how these arise. Maybe I am misunderstanding entirely what rebase does?

Note: After successfully rebasing branch1 onto B of branch2, I intend to reset master to A, so the final version is supposed to look the following way.

```
A                  master
 \
  B -- E -- F      branch2
   \
    C -- D         branch1
```

Comment: Why not just reset `master` to `A`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What happens with `branch1` if I just reset `master`? I'm trying to establish a staging/development branch with `branch2`.. and reset `master` to the version that should currently be deployed..

Comment: In Git branch is just a pointer to commit. So, when you move pointer `master`, then pointer `branch1` will still be pointing to the same commit as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some problems with your assumptions. First, branches are just pointers to commits. You start with this, and `master` is checked out.

```
       C -- D      branch1
      /     
A -- B -- E -- F   master
```

After `git branch branch2` you have this.

```
       C -- D      branch1
      /     
A -- B -- E -- F   master & branch2
```

Note there is no stub branch, `master` and `branch2` both point at F. Aside from their names, they are indistinguishable.

Once you checkout `branch2` and `git rebase A` nothing changes. `branch2` already has `A` in its ancestry, it remains pointing at `F`. You should have gotten a message like `Current branch branch2 is up to date`.

When you did `git checkout branch1` and `git rebase --onto B branch2` this confused things. There's an assumed third argument, the currently checked out branch. What you actually ran is `git rebase --onto B branch2 branch1`. That says "take the commits reachable by branch1 but not by branch 2 (the same as `git log branch2..branch1` or C and D) and put them onto B". This should be a no-op, but if branch1 and branch2 have any changes in common the rebase will throw them out.

If C and E made the same changes you'd wind up with this, and probably a conflict.

```
       C -- D      original branch1
      /     
A -- B -- E -- F   master & branch2
      \
       D1 branch1
```

This doesn't make much sense, but that's what happens when you try to rebase between two cousins.

Also note that the rebased branch has the id D1, not D. Commit IDs incorporate the ID of their parents, so the ID must change. `rebase` does not rewrite history, it creates new history and tells you that's how it always was. A subtle but important distinction. Your original commit is still there... for a while.

---

If you want to go from this:

```
       C -- D      branch1
      /     
A -- B -- E -- F   master & branch2
```

To this.

```
A                  master
 \
  B -- E -- F      branch2
   \
    C -- D         branch1
```

That can be flipped over so it aligns with what you have better.

```
       C -- D      branch1
      /     
     B -- E -- F   branch2
    /
   A               master
```

All you need to do is move `master` to A. There's several ways to do this, one is `git branch -f master A`. This forces `master` to move to `A`.